# Changing the button BackColor Property

Tags: c#-2.0

I want to change the backcolor of the Button when the buttonFlatStyle property
is set to System.is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.
When the `FlatStyle` property i set to `System` the appearance of the control is determined by the user's operating system.

For more info see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flatstyle.aspx